# Vim,how to escape &?

Tags: vim

Simply question,i want to search & as exact word,how to do in vim?
I had try \& and \<&> but doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "exact word"?

Comment: You're aware of the existence of the [Vi and Vim site](http://vi.stackexchange.com), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for a plain `&` (unescaped) and you will match this character. If you want the `&` surrounded by whitespace (or rather alone at a word boundary) you'd type `\<&\>`. (Both of those regexps must be initiated by `vim`'s search command `/`.)

Note the difference: `\` is the *escape character* for a special interpretation of the subsequent character, and `/` is `vim`'s *search forward* command (and `?` used to *search backward*).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to remember whether to put a `\` before a non-alphanumeric character, put `\v` ("very magic") or `\V` ("very nonmagic") at the beginning of your search.  If you use "very magic", any literal symbol will require a backslash.  With "very nonmagic", all symbols will be literal *unless* they have a backslash.